# Google Cloud Function running on nodejs10 test fails

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Here are the relevant bits of my function:

```
    // Finally send the JSON data to the browser or requestor
    res.status(200).send(output);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  } finally {
    await closeConnection(page, browser);
  }
```

When I run this locally it works flawlessly and returns my output to the web browser. When I upload it to Google Cloud Functions and test it the `res.status(200).send(output);` line fails with this message:

```
Error: function execution failed. Details:
res.status is not a function
```

Has anyone else seen this behavior? I'm completely puzzled as to why it would work perfectly on my local machine, but fail when I run it as a cloud function.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the [complete minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces this error.  What you have now is not enough to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around a bunch I found the answer. Google Cloud Functions that have a 'background' trigger type do not recognize `res.status`. Instead they want `callback`:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#function_parameters

```
    // Finally send the JSON data to the browser or requestor
    callback(null, output);
  } catch (err) {
    callback(new Error('Failed'));
  } finally {
    await closeConnection(page, browser);
  }
```

If you run your local development instance with the --signature-type flag it correctly starts up, but you can no longer test by hitting the port in a web browser:

```
    "start": "functions-framework --target=pollenCount --signature-type=cloudevent",
```

Documentation on how to send mock pub/sub data into your local instance is here:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/calling#background_functions